# CakePHP 3 session renew

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, session-timeout

I am working with CakePHP 3 and also I use the build in AuthComponent.
I have a page that I don't want the session to expire in order not to log out the users.

What is the best practice to renew the session id ?
I thought to make an ajax request every 10 min. to renew the session before expiration. 
    $this->request->session()->renew();
Will the method renew in session work for this ?

Is any better solution ?

Comment: Have you considered just making the session length longer? For example, you could make it so that they're not logged out, even after a few hours of inactivity.

Comment: if i change the session it will apply the setting for all of my pages, i dont want that, i want only to one specific page where is a dashboard for monitoring

Answer (score 2):

Just sending a request to CakePHP and reading from the session, maybe just reading the user id, will extend the session time for the user. There is no need to call `renew()`